# Disable camera feature used in all applications

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

How to disable camera feature used by other application from my application without device admin permission in marshmallow and above.

single instance of camera is not working is marshmallow.

Comment: If its marshmallow, I don't think its possible to get your desired output without asking permission, Correct me if am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

try this 
you can disable or enable camera but your app must device admin enabled.Following enables or disable camera:-

```
devicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(compName, isCameraOn);
```

**isCameraOn** is boolean true or false